# PHP/MYSQL where keyword in MYSQLI table, unable to display the results

Tags: php, mysql

What i am trying to do is to display all rows where there is a matching entry in $st_id_get_2.

$st_id_get_2 will always contain a single keyword, so when clicking the keyword on the website it goes through the database and shows all rows where the keyword is listed in the column "kb_keywords"

```
        echo "<table class='' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>";
        $sql3aa = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM knowledgebase_items WHERE kb_visible = 'Yes' and kb_keywords IN ($st_id_get_2)");
        while ($row3aa = $sql3aa->fetch_assoc()){

        echo "<tr><td width='50%'><blockquote class='message'><a class='hover' href='../" . $row3aa['kb_ID'] . "'>" . $row3aa['kb_subject'] . "</a></blockquote></td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
```

So the error message i am getting is this:

[image]

The current database structure for reference is:

[image]

I can not seem to get what i have done wrong here.

I believe the problem is here:

```
kb_keywords IN ($st_id_get_2)
```

But i am not sure what i have done wrong, can i get some advice please to point out my error ?

An example of $st_id_get_2 could be "user", "account", "report"

But there will only ever be one word in each $st_id_get_2 at any time, you can go onto the website and click the keyword button which passes the variable to the query.

This is an example of what the keywords look like in the screenshot below, this is just sample data.

[image]

Thanks

David

Comment: can you give a sample value of $st_id_get_2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use **LIKE** here instead of **IN**

```
"SELECT * FROM knowledgebase_items WHERE kb_visible = 'Yes' and kb_keywords LIKE '%".$st_id_get_2."%'"
```

OR for exact matching

```
"SELECT * FROM knowledgebase_items WHERE kb_visible = 'Yes' and kb_keywords LIKE '".$st_id_get_2."'"
```

Comment: Hi Reza thanks that is perfect, for me using the code for LIKE works exactly as needed instead of exact matching. Thanks ! Been driving me mad all day !

Comment: Yes i had to wait 10 mins before accepting your answer :) All done now and accepted.